# Reading Rss into DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, datatable, rss

I am reading RSS and converting into a dataTable. This is the code i am using.

This is my rss format

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>First Choice Liquor</title>
<link>https://www.1stchoice.com.au</link>
<copyright>(c) 2015, First Choice Liquor</copyright>
  <item>
    <title>McWilliams Hanwood Chardonnay 750mL in any six</title>
    <product_name>McWilliams Hanwood Chardonnay 750mL</product_name>

    <description>
    Inexpensive chardonnay need not be ordinary. Complexity and elegance on a budget. A blend of Chardonnays from all over the… Price may vary per state.
    </description>
    <link>
    https://www.1stchoice.com.au/White Wine/mcwilliams-hanwood-chardonnay-750ml_121385?forceState=QLD
    </link>
 </item>
 <item>...<item>
 <item>...<item>
 <item>...<item>
</channel>
```

I want my DataTable to have only three columns.

```
title, product_name, description
```

And then rows filled the relevant values.

```
string url = "http://localhost/sample_qld.xml";
XElement x = XElement.Load(url);
DataTable dtr = BuildDataTable(x);

private static DataTable BuildDataTable(XElement x)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("title"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("product_name"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("description"));
        foreach (var d in x.Descendants())
        {
            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
            if (x.Name.ToString() == "title")
            {
                drow[0] = d.Value;
            }
            if (x.Name.ToString() == "product_name")
            {
                drow[1] = d.Value;
            }
            if (x.Name.ToString() == "description")
            {
                drow[2] = d.Value;
            }
        }

    return dt;
}
```

Right now i am able to all RSS XML into xElement X which has all the xml but i am not able to make data table as i wanted. Any help of what i am doing wrong? I simple need three columns with rows

Comment: I gave you an answer in your last question and you delete the question. You have downvote for that !

Comment: @mybirthname: I was the one who deleted the question.  It was off-topic, and so was this one.  If you don't want your answers deleted along with the question, try to choose better questions to answer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Here I post the answer **AGAIN** ! Next time don't delete question with answers, especially when they are **upvoted** !

```
        string url = "http://www.test.com/feed/";
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Columns.Add("Title");

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();

            String title= item.Title.Text;
            row["Title"]= title;
            table.Rows.Add(row);   
        }
```

You need to use [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) to read rss. You need `System.ServiceModel` reference to be added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the row to the table. Just creating a new one won't automatically add it to the table:

```
            foreach (var d in x.Descendants())
        {
            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
            if (x.Name.ToString() == "title")
            {

                drow[0] = d.Value;

            }
            if (x.Name.ToString() == "product_name")
            {

                drow[1] = d.Value;

            }
            if (x.Name.ToString() == "description")
            {

                drow[2] = d.Value;

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(drow);
        }
```

Comment: well this is not working my x.Name.ToString() is "rss" everytime

Comment: Descendants () is not recursive. I'm not at anyplace I can test the code right now but you need to drill in deeper, something like Descendants().Elements("item")